# How to clear the left most bit (that is set) of a binary number

Tags: binary, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, cpu-architecture

I was reading [this](http://ev.fe.uni-lj.si/1-2010/Babic.pdf) paper about a **binary multiplier unit**. The paper proposes an architecture for an iterative logarithmic multiplier. The block diagram of the proposed architecture is shown below :

[image]

The entire block diagram is not important, the question relates to a very small part of it. I wish to know how is `N1 - 2^k1` calculated. The diagram shows a LOD (I don't know what that is) block, followed by an XOR gate, and it generates the value of N1 - 2^k1, which is basically `clearing the left most bit that is set`.

I don't understand this. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They mention in the text that it's a Leading One Detector, that is, it forms of a mask that indicates which bit (if any) is the leading one in its input. That's actually kind of obvious, because that's precisely what we know it *should* be doing from the semantics.

A possible implementation of the LOD is given in one of the references.

Comment: Doesn't priority encoder also work as a leading one detector?

Comment: @ironstein sort of but they need a mask here, not an index